# XPath: How to select a node by its attribute?

Tags: c#, xml, xpath

I have an XML that goes like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<colors>
  <color index = "0">#FF0000</color>
  <color index = "1">#FF0200</color>
  <color index = "2">#FF0300</color>
  <color index = "3">#FF0500</color>
  [..]
```

I'm trying to select a node by its index:

```
XmlDocument ColorTable = new XmlDocument();
ColorTable.Load(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/ColorTable.xml"));
int percentage = 2;
string xpath = string.Format(@"//color[index={0}]", percentage.ToString());
//string xpath = string.Format(@"//color[index=""{0}""]", percentage.ToString());
//string xpath = string.Format(@"//color[index='{0}']", percentage.ToString());
var r = ColorTable.SelectSingleNode(xpath).Value;
```

I tried also the commented versions, but it does not return any result.
Any suggestion?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use `//color[@index='{0}']` instead. The @ sign means "attribute".

I note that you're using a verbatim string literal by the way - the @ sign at the *start* of the string. There's no need in this case - you don't have any backslashes in the string, and it's not multi-line. You also don't need to explicitly call `ToString` on `percentage` - it will be converted automatically.

```
string xpath = string.Format("//color[@index='{0}']", percentage);
```

Comment: Why does the 0 have to be enclosed in curly braces?  I use XPATH inside Novell IDM, and @index=0 would have been sufficient there.  What do the curly braces indicate?

Comment: its not part of the xpath, it's part of the String.Format, it will be replaces with the 1st param (ie percentage)

Answer (score 9):

BTW, for those of us who doesn't speak native XPath, [there are many online XPath "playgrounds"](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&q=Online+XPATH&meta=)
that allow you to write XML and XPath expression and see the results online.

Whenever I found myself in a "*XPath hell*" I usually go to those [playgrounds](http://www.futurelab.ch/xmlkurs/xpath.en.html) and try various combination till I get my (needed) results, for some reason it works faster than writing  C#/Python test program or even running those [bloated](http://www.altova.com/) so called XML editors.