# Read XML Value By Attribute Name

Tags: c#, xml, xmlnode, xml-attribute

```
<Customer>
    <Type H="General Information" ID="GeneralInfo">
         <Row>
             <C H="Customer Name">Mr. Robert</C>
             <C H="Relation">S/O. John</C>
             <C H="Date of Birth">01/01/1985</C>
        </Row>
    </Type>
    <Type H = "Other Details" ID = "ShareDet">
         <Row>
            <C H = "Address 1">XYZ</C>
            <C H = "Address 2">ABC</C>
        </Row>
    </Type>
</Customer>
```

I am trying to read "Mr. Robert" from above XML in C# but i could not.
I tried  below Code:

```
XmlDocument objXmlMain = new XmlDocument();
objXmlMain.LoadXml("Loading_Above_XMLSTRING");
string test = objXmlMain.SelectSingleNode("Customer/Type/Row/C/@H").Value;
```

I am getting result as "**Customer Name**" (That is attribute value).
I want to read the Name by checking attribute value "Customer Name" and i should get result as "**Mr. Robert**"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [XPath: How to select a node by its attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1068210/xpath-how-to-select-a-node-by-its-attribute)

Comment: or any results of internet search with `c# xpath by attribute name`

Answer (score 1):

You need to use:

```
string test = objXmlMain.SelectSingleNode("Customer/Type/Row/C[@H='Customer Name']").Value;
```

The `Customer/Type/Row/C/@H` xpath query selects the `H` attribute itself and `.Value` returns the text of that attribute.